# Searching for correlation between one variable and 4 other variables (separately)

Tags: regression, correlation

I have calculated a few scores in my data, I'd call them d1, d2, d3, d4.
I'm trying to see which score has correlation with an independent variable, ept-score.
I'm planning to calculate Spearman's Rho for ept-score and d1, ept-score and d2, ept-score and d3, ept-score and d4. For all four dependent variables, d1, d2, d3, d4, there are outliers. Do I remove them together before running the analysis? Or independently before calculating a particular correlation?

I have tried both, but I'm not sure what would be most appropriate.